# igraph not working on the Spyder IDE on windows

Tags: python, installation, pip, igraph, spyder

I am trying to use igraph on Spyder. I think I have installed it correctly following the instructions on the igraph website (for python igraph on windows using an unofficial installer). It seems to work on the pycharm IDE but not on Spyder.

When I try to run some code, this is the error I get:

```
DeprecationWarning: To avoid name collision with the igraph project, this visualization library has been renamed to 'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.
```

Comment: 1st, it's not an error, just a warning. 2nd, why not follow the advice from the author? The library was renamed so why not use it under the new name?

Comment: I agree. The message is clearly a warning and it even says the way to solve it, so I don't understand what's the problem here.

Comment: If you want help, it would be a good idea to provide the code that produced the error.

Comment: I think I was too much of a noob to even understand that it was giving me an error. Why does it ask me to change it to jgraph?